# Types of licence in odoo manifest descriptor

Tags: odoo, odoo-9, odoo-10

**Odoo Manifest**

I want to know how many types of licence are available in odoo for adding in manifest descriptor. as we see an example below `'license': 'OEEL-1',`

```
{
    'name': 'Module Name',
    'version': '1.1',
    'installable': True,
    'auto_install': True,
    'license': 'OEEL-1',
}
```

Answer (score 5):

According to the [source code](https://github.com/odoo/odoo/blob/d8e49d3886ab7c5443b9173bd9b3e45e05b72c6c/odoo/addons/base/module/module.py#L256-L266), the following values are supported:

- GPL-2
- GPL-2 or any later version
- GPL-3
- GPL-3 or any later version
- AGPL-3
- LGPL-3
- Other OSI approved licence
- OEEL-1
- OPL-1
- Other proprietary